# Linearly dependent columns of product of matrices

Tags: matrices, matrix-rank

I have been struggling with proving a relation regarding the smallest number of linearly dependent columns of product of matrices. Any insights would be greatly appreciated.

Let $m$ and $n$ be the smallest number of linearly dependent columns of matrices $A$ and $B$ respectively. Then, what can we say about the smallest number of linearly dependent columns of the product matrix $AB$?

An analogous property exists for the largest number of columns that are linearly independent; in other words, the rank of the matrix i.e. $rank(AB) \leq min(rank(A), rank(B))$.

Can we say something similar about the smallest number of linearly dependent columns of the product of two matrices?

> Edit:
>
> As pointed out by user164568, this is equivalent to asking how $spark(AB)$ is related to $spark(A)$ and $spark(B)$?

-RD

Answer (score 0):

Just a comment to your question: what you are referring to here is called *spark* of the matrix. Spark is the smallest number of linearly dependent columns of the matrix.

Comment: Thanks. I have modified the question to reflect this.